# Размытие вокруг прицела?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня на холсте есть прицел.

[image: изначальный вариант сцены]

С внешней стороны нужно чтобы было размыто. У меня есть материал с размытием.

[image: пример размытия части изображения]

Но если вставлять картинкой, то идеально обвести не получается. Как решить данную проблему? Нужно рациональное решение.

Нужно размыть всю вот эту область (внутри прицела не надо).

[image: для какой области хотелось бы установить размытие]

Comment: Кстати, снизу более реалистично (хоть и незнакомый прицел). Картинка в глазу всегда немного плывет

Comment: Это конечно не ответ на вопрос, но зону за пределами оптики полностью скрывают, что бы не было видно, что "приближено" не только то что в акуляре, но и всё остальное за его пределами, потому, что это приближена камера, а не эффект линзы.

Comment: @Yaroslav дада я понимаю, но тут надо сделать именно так :)

Comment: @Yaroslav вышло уже несколько тайтлов с реализацией двух камер, внутри линзы приближено, снаружи - нет.

Comment: Ни одна ААА уровня так не делает.

Comment: @Yaroslav в CoD: Modern Warfare (2019) именно так и реализованы все прицелы. Из AA - Escape from Tarkov. Не очень похоже на "ни одна" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Нарисуйте картинку с дыркой под окуляр.
- Помещаете на `Canvas` как `Image` и добавляете компонент `Mask`.
- Помещаете объект с блюром, как дочерний к этой картинке.
- Раскаивайтесь в том что наделали.

Comment: Спасибо! До этого делал без маски прост )

Comment: @grouptout а вот без маски не надо, карантин же. (^_^)